# Sending a byte from Processing to Arduino

Tags: arduino, processing

I'm trying to send over a stream of bytes (0-255) from Processing to Arduino over Serial.

Processing Code:

```java
int a = 234;
byte b = (byte)a;
Serial.write(b);
```

Arduino Code:

```java
byte a = Serial.read();
```

Now, if I were to do:

```java
Serial.print(a);
```

would I get 234 or a negative value?

Comment: You should get a 0-255 value on the Arduino side: you can always write a basic Arduino sketch and use Serial Monitor to test. Be aware when reading bytes back in java though as byte is signed (-127,127)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean (byte)a?

If so, you will get 234 for my known.

when you write (byte) before the integer the compiler know to take only the last byte form the 4 byte integer. More then this, byte cant be a negative value (is just from 0-255).

Hope i help.

yoav